# Convert CSV to XML using Groovy Scripting

Tags: xml, csv, groovy

I have a CSV text file and want to create a structure of XML from it 
the input looks like this :

```
1,MID,120,XX
2,MTS,223,yy
```

the output should be

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <field1>1</field1>
    <field2>MID</field2>
    <field3>120</field3>
    <field4>XX</field4>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <field1>2</field1>
    <field2>MTS</field2>
    <field3>223</field3>
    <field4>yy</field4>
  </Row>
</Root>
```

I'm new in Groovy, thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? We're not here to do your homework..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSV parser, and a MarkupBuilder

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.1')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv
import groovy.xml.*

def csv = '''1,MID,120,XX
2,MTS,223,yy
'''


def writer = new StringWriter()
def data = parseCsv(csv, readFirstLine: true)
new MarkupBuilder(writer).root {
    data.each { row ->
        Row {
            row.values.eachWithIndex { k, idx -> 
                 "Value$idx"(k)
            } 
        }
    }
}

println writer.toString()
```